# Primitive datatype error in java?

Tags: java

I'm new to java programming language, could somebody please tell me the reason for following error.

```
 public class TestPrimitives {

        int a;
        a  = 10;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            TestPrimitives cn = new TestPrimitives();

            System.out.println(cn.a);
        }

    }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class a
  location: class beginner.TestPrimitives
    at beginner.TestPrimitives.<init>(TestPrimitives.java:15)
    at beginner.TestPrimitives.main(TestPrimitives.java:18)
```

Comment: you can´t do a single `a = 10;` outside of a method, constructor or initializer block. But you could define and assign `a` in one line `int  a = 10;`

Comment: I'd also *strongly* recommend avoiding trying to run code that hasn't compiled. We don't know what your environment is, but I would be surprised if you ran it without having to click through a warning saying that the code hadn't compiled properly. At that point, the right step is almost always to *not* run the code.

Comment: Hint: you also shouldn't try to **run** a java program ... if the **java compiler** already told you: this is not valid java.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initilize variable outside code block

```
a  = 10;
```

Initilize variable at declaration time

```
int a = 10;
```

or in init block

```
public class TestPrimitives {

    int a;

    {
        a  = 10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestPrimitives cn = new TestPrimitives();

        System.out.println(cn.a);
    }

}
```

Comment: could you please explain the reason behind it? Is it a constraint present in java or is that how java is designed?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize values in:

1. Constructor
2. Method
3. Initializing block

or try this:

```
int a = 10;
```